# Source Tree Push : hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

Tags: git, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to push my application with Source Tree.

I reverted the application (locally) to an old version, made some changes and now I want to push again, but I'm getting this error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream origin dev:dev
Pushing to https://user@bitbucket.org/hykaruz/assist-ponto.git
To https://user@bitbucket.org/hykaruz/project.git
 ! [rejected]        dev -> dev (non-fast-forward)



error: failed to push some refs to 'https:/User:bitbucket.org/hykaruz/Project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

PS. My version was too old, I had to download the last version then I can commit and push my application, so if you get the same problem check to see if there's an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your commit history diverges from the upstream repository (you didn't just add more commits), git refuses to push the changes **because you can lose work this way**.

If you are sure you want to overwrite the upstream repository history with your own (e.g., you are the only one pushing to that repository), you have to add `-f` to force the push.

Comment: Thanks , I'm the only one on the moment pushing in this repository. thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry I'm prerty New , I'm pushing from the Source Tree, where do I add -f?

Comment: After `push` (you can see this in SYNOPSIS section when you do `man git-push`)

Comment: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin dev:dev
Pushing to https://user@bitbucket.org/hykaruz/project.git
To https://user@bitbucket.org/hykaruz/project.git -f , put that in the promp ?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I've understood. You should put the `-f` immediately after `push` and that should be fine.

Comment: I've never used Source Tree Before,  but Thank you for the patience.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I never used Source Tree either. I am pushing using the command line. You can run the git command (`git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin dev:dev` if I'm not missing something) manually, adding the `-f` there.

Sorry for messing you up.

Comment: Oh man , sorry I didnt see that I dont put that information on my question ,  Thanks you, Now its all fine ... Thank you for you patience.

Answer (score 1):

In my case for exact same error, I was not the only developer.

So I went to commit & push my changes at same time, seen at bottom of the `Commit` dialog popup:

[image: Checked option for: Push changes immediately to origin]

...but I made the huge mistake of forgetting to hit the `Fetch` button to see if I have latest, which I did not.

The commit successfully executed, however not the push, but instead gives the same mentioned error;
...even though other developers didn't alter same files as me, I cannot pull latest as same error is presented.

## The GUI Solution

Most of the time I prefer sticking with Sourcetree's **GUI (Graphical User Interface)**. This solution might not be ideal, however this is what got things going again for me without worrying that I may lose my changes or compromise more recent updates from other developers.

### STEP 1

Right-click on the commit right before yours to undo your locally committed changes and select `Reset current branch to this commit` like so:

[image: Sourcetree window with right-clicked commit and selecting: Reset current branch to this commit]

### STEP 2

Once all the loading spinners disappear and Sourcetree is done loading the previous commit, at the top-left of window, click on `Pull` button...

[image: Sourcetree window with with the Pull button highlighted]

...then a dialog popup will appear, and click the **`OK`** button at bottom-right:

[image: Sourcetree window dialog popup with the OK button highlighted]

### STEP 3

After pulling latest, if you do not get any errors, skip to **STEP 4** (next step below). Otherwise if you discover any merge conflicts at this point, like I did with my `Web.config` file:

[image: Sourcetree window showing the error hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind]

...then click on the `Stash` button at the top, a dialog popup will appear and you will need to write a Descriptive-name-of-your-changes, then click the **`OK`** button:

[image: Sourcetree window with Stash button highlighted and dialog popup showing input to name your stash with OK button highlighted]

...once Sourcetree is done stashing your altered file(s), repeat actions in **STEP 2** (previous step above), and then your local files will have latest changes. Now your changes can be reapplied by opening your `STASHES` seen at bottom of Sourcetree left column, use the arrow to expand your stashes, then right-click to choose `Apply Stash 'Descriptive-name-of-your-changes'`, and after select **`OK`** button in dialog popup that appears:

[image: Sourcetree window with the Stashes section expanded and changes right-clicked with Apply Stash highlighted]

[image: Sourcetree dialog popup ask your to confirm if you would like to apply stash you your local copy]

IF you have any Merge Conflict(s) right now, go to your preferred text-editor, like Visual Studio Code, and in the affected files select the `Accept Incoming Change` link, then save:

[image]

Then back to Sourcetree, click on the `Commit` button at top:

[image]

then right-click on the conflicted file(s), and under `Resolve Conflicts` select the `Mark Resolved` option:

[image]

### STEP 4

Finally!!! We are now able to commit our file(s), also checkmark the `Push changes immediately to origin` option before clicking the `Commit` button:

[image]

P.S. while writing this, a commit was submitted by another developer right before I got to commit, so had to pretty much repeat steps.